# How to comment on a PEP?

Tags: python

Proposals for new Python features are collected in documents called PEPs (Python Enhancement Proposals). There's a master list at http://www.python.org/dev/peps/ which links to (for example):

- Labeled break and continue
  http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3136/
- Asynchronous IO support
  http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3153/
- Remove Backslash Continuation
  http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3125/

It's great that proposals are published publicly for the community to read. However, how is the community supposed to participate? The pages don't allow comments.

It strikes me as weird the Python developers would make proposals public then deliberately exclude the community from discussion. Have I missed something?

In particular, I'd like to read other people's comments on http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0453/ and add my own.

---

For comparison, Ruby feature proposals are made as posts to its bug tracker. You can read everyone's comments below, and add your own (after making an account)

- Refinements and nested methods https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4085
- Frozen string syntax https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8579
- Exception#cause to carry originating exception along with new one  https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8257

Nodejs feature requests are plain GitHub issues, which is probably the most inclusive. It's very easy to join GitHub and post a comment.

- https://github.com/joyent/node/issues?labels=feature-request

Comment: related: [Why do some big projects, like Git and Debian, only use a mailing list and not an issue tracker?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/191961/31260)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python PEPs are discussed on the [Python-Dev mailinglist](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-dev), which anyone is free to join.

There is a [Gmane gateway for web reading](http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.devel) too.

I do advice you to study the [Python developer's guide](http://docs.python.org/devguide/) before wading into any discussions, though. The contained FAQ has some entries on [communication](http://docs.python.org/devguide/faq.html#communications) that cover new feature discussions as well.

The Python community formed in the early 1990, and the community established itself around mailinglists (built on the now-venerable [Mailman list manager](http://www.list.org/)) and newsgroups (`comp.lang.python` is gatewayed to the python@mail.python.org list), and the model has worked well enough for this community.

Comment: Hi Martijn. "It's on a mailing list" what does that mean--how would I post a reply to http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0453/  -- could you give a worked example? I have a Gmail address, if that helps.

Comment: @ColonelPanic: You write an email to the list with a subject that reflects the PEP you are commenting on. Do try to see what other discussion has already taken place.

Comment: @ColonelPanic: A quick search on the Gmane mirror returns http://search.gmane.org/?query=pep+453&group=gmane.comp.python.devel. Sample thread at http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.devel/142069/focus=142159

Comment: Is it possible to read all the comments on one page in chronological order? The results you link are individual replies to replies to replies eg. http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.devel/142159/match=pep+453 . It's incredibly hard to follow the conversation that way.

Comment: Also, how can I comment from Gmail? Do I need to use a special subject header so my comment shows up on the right page?

Comment: @ColonelPanic: No, you just send email to the `python-dev@python.org` list. It's a mailinglist, you send email to it. :-) If you use the same subject header it'll work.

Comment: @ColonelPanic: you may want to subscribe to the list too, so you see all responses that are just sent to the list and not cc-ed to you as well.

Comment: @ColonelPanic: As for chronological views of the mail archives, you could look through the [Mailman archive copy](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/), but the interface is a little more.. static and cumbersome as there is no search. This is all 1990s tech.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll try that. I've used mailing lists before, but didn't know how to reply to threads created before I joined.